# Для чего создан символ "U+0000"?

Tags: unicode

Недавно наткнулся на символ, которого нет. То есть он, в отличии от U+200C или U+200B, даже не печатается. Так для чего он тогда нужен?

Comment: Это не юникодный символ, это управляющий символ (null character) из таблицы ASCII. В некоторых языках используется для обозначения конца строки (т.к. строка представлена просто указателем).

Comment: Угу, в C это конец строки. Да и вообще прикольно: типа символ ничего. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @etki так как обозначить конец строки, если сам символ исчезает? И для этого создан, например, U+200C

Comment: @VladGavriuk это резервированный символ. В с/с++/ещё где-нибудь конец строки это /0. Символ с 0 кодом там в строку просто не добавить. Вот для совместимости он и нужен именно таким. И именно конец строки, а не перенос или ещё что-то

Comment: @etki конечно [U+0000](https://codepoints.net/U+0000) это юникодный символ (Unicode codepoint). ascii это просто кодировка (одна из многих). Можно закодировать (превратить символ в байты), используя любую кодировку, которая может символ представить, к примеру: `u'\0'.encode('utf-16be') ==  b'\x00\x00'`

Comment: @jfs я имел в виду, что он пришел из ascii и юникод над ним никакого контроля не имеет

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[U+0000](https://codepoints.net/U+0000) существует в Юникоде для совместимости с более старыми
стандартами, которые создавались в эпоху когда ещё [биты физически на
бумаге с помощью дырок выставляли](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_(%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)).

Аналог предшествующих стандартов на русском ([ГОСТ
27465-87](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/gost-27465-87)) определяет
<kbd>ПУС</kbd> символ (`ПУСТО`) как:

> Символ, назначением которого является заполнение носителя или временного
>   интервала. Символ ПУС может быть введен в поток информации или
>   исключен из него без оказания влияния на содержание информации, в этом
>   случае прибавление или исключение этого символа может повлиять на
>   размещение информации и (или) управление аппаратурой

Поэтому вывод:

```py
>>> print('\u0435\u0308')
ё
```

и:

```py
>>> print('\u0435' + '\0'*1000 + '\u0308')
ё
```

может выглядеть одинаково, хотя вторая команда печатает на тысячу символов больше.

Намерение стандарта (как я его понимаю), в том что битовое представление символа `ПУСТО` не имеет дырок (например, из одних нулей состоит, если `1` соответствует дырке), не оставляет следов на бумаге -- поэтому можно использовать <kbd>ПУС</kbd>, чтобы к примеру зарезервировать место на [перфоленте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_(%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)) для будущих вставок или просто дать время аппаратуре предыдущие действия закончить (аналог [NOP инструкции, которая предписывает ничего не делать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)).

*На практике*, `\0` байт (который может превратиться в U+0000
Юникодный символ при декодировании, используя основанную на ascii
кодировку) может служить индикатором конца строки (в C) или
разделителем отдельных строк в текстовом потоке (NUL как правило не
может встретиться внутри ожидаемых строк, поэтому этот символ служит
хорошим разделителем).

К примеру, `find -print0` команда печатает пути, разделённые
NUL (`\0` не может быть частью имени файла в *nix) -- это
позволяет обрабатывать файлы с экзотическими именами, содержащие новые
строки или любые другие байты. Вот конкретный пример кода, который получает
переменные окружения из дочернего процесса, используя `env -0` команду
(`\0` байт разделяет отдельные записи, так как переменная окружения на
POSIX не может содержать NUL) -- [Calling the “source” command from
`subprocess.Popen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22086176/4279).