# Что делают символы unicode из категории "Other, control"?

Tags: unicode

Зачем созданы символы на подобии U+007F(DELETE)? Такой `DELETE` ничего не удаляет, я пробовал. И там ещё масса таких символов, вот список:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm

Так зачем же такие символы нужны? И как их применять?

Comment: А как вы это пробовали ? В редакторе под windows он может ничего и не удаляет, а в консоли unix еще как удаляет. так же и остальные управляющие символы, они созданы для _управления_ терминалом. Часть ОС, которым они нужны их понимают, другая часть ОС игнорируют

Comment: @Mike я пробовал в редакторах linux ubuntu, но не в консоле.

Comment: Вы в редакторе введите этот символ а потом выведите файл на консоль с помощью cat. Только убедитесь в шестнадцетиричном редакторе, что в файле действительно 0x7F. При вводе с клавиатуры эти символы могут чем нибудь подменяться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Зачем созданы символы на подобии U+007F(DELETE)?

[U+007F](https://codepoints.net/U+007F) (DEL, `ЗАБОЙ`,
<kbd>ЗБ</kbd>) это
противоположность [U+0000 (NUL, `ПУСТО`)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685870/23044) с теми же корнями времён,
когда [биты физически дырками на бумаге обозначались](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_(%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)). Определение символа `ЗАБОЙ` из [ГОСТ
27465-87](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/gost-27465-87):

> Символ, предназначенный для уничтожения ошибочных и ненужных символов на носителе ([перфоленте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_(%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8))).

```
 /\/\/\/\/|
|     .   |  ␀
|     .   |  ␀
| o o . oo|  S
| ooo .o  |  t
| oo  .  o|  a
| oo  . oo|  c
| oooo.ooo|  ␡
| oo o. oo|  k
|  o  .   |  ␠
| o  o.ooo|  O
| ooo .oo |  v
| oo  .o o|  e
| ooo . o |  r
| oo  .oo |  f
| oo o.o  |  l
| oo o.ooo|  o
| ooo .ooo|  w
|    o. o |  New Line
|     .   |  ␀
|     .   |  ␀
|/\/\/\/\/
```

В (искусственном) примере выше, лента содержит данные в ASCII
кодировке (`"Stack Overflow\n"`). Начало и конец ленты не содержат
дырок и соответствуют символу `ПУСТО` и наоборот когда все дырки
пробиты это соответствует символу `ЗАБОЙ`:

```
0000_000 ␀
1100_001 a
1100_011 c
1111_111 ␡
```

То есть, намерение в том, что если введён не тот символ, то его можно
стереть *забив* поверх символом, состоящим из одних единиц, то есть
символом `ЗАБОЙ`. Также как и NUL, DEL иначе игнорируется (поэтому суммарный эффект в том, что
забитый поверх символ стирается).

```py
>>> print('\u0435' + chr(0b1111_111) + '\u0308')
ё
```

[*На
практике*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character#Current_use),
на моей машине
[stty](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html)
в терминале показывает, что `ЗАБОЙ` используется в качестве erase
управляющего символа (стирает *предыдущий* символ). Нажатие
<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> в консоли выводит `^?` (`ЗАБОЙ` в caret notation).

### Что делают символы unicode из категории “Other, control”?

Включая U+0000 и U+007F, в Юникоде 65 управляющих символа (code points:
[`U+0000..U+001F` и `U+007F..U+009F`](https://codepoints.net/search?gc=Cc)), существующих для совместимости с [C0
и C1 управляющими
кодами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes). **Unicode
стандарт ([23.1 Control
Codes](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/UnicodeStandard-10.0.pdf))
не изменяет *смысл этих кодов*, который в общем случае *определяется
приложениями* *или* в отсутствии другой семантики *ISO/IEC 6429:1992
стандартом*.** См. [ECMA-48 (редакция ISO/IEC
6429)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf)

Семантика, определяемая стандартом (которая может не использоваться на
практике, если конкретное приложение определяет своё значение),
слабо поменялась с ANSI_X3.4-1968. Из [RFC 20 (копия
определения из ASCII)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc20):

> DEL (Delete): This character is used primarily to "erase" or "obliterate" erroneous or unwanted characters in perforated tape.

Если есть интерес к происхождению ascii кодов, можно почитать
неформальную историю [The Evolution of Character Codes,
1874-1968](http://trafficways.org/ascii/ascii.pdf) (для плавного введения в соосную тему подойдёт книга Чарльза Петцольда: «Код. Тайный язык информатики»), а также посмотреть
на дальнейшее [развитие стандартов для управляющих символов до их
включения в Unicode](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/control-characters.html):

[image: From ASCII via ISO to Unicode]