# python unicode не дает копировать из одной базы в другую

Tags: python, postgresql

Я достаю данные из базы MSSQL и тут же вставляю в другую на postgres
Какая то часть строк проходит без вопросов, но

А начиная с 56 ругается

```
ValueError: A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters.
```

Массив данных полученный из MSSQL 
выглядит так

```
row[x] = {unicode} u'ДействуетÓ'
```

Я думаю проблема в этих строках из там штук 5, ну естественно с разными значениями, и также есть числовые

Как то может их экранировать? или преобразовывать? пытаюсь делать encode пишет что объект не имеет методов

Answer (score 2):

В общем дело было в строке, в некоторых строках был 0x00 байт в конце строки, я удаляю этот байт перед вставкой в postgres, оказывается ругается на этот байт - библиотека psycopg2. Искал в интернете, что говорят там что то коментируют в коде библиотеки и все норм. Но я так и не нашел что закомментировать, а просто удаляю этот нулевой байт

```
row[9] = row[9].replace(chr(0x00), "")
```

Comment: в текстовых данных (Unicode) NUL обычно не должен попадаться [Для чего создан символ "U+0000"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685870/23044) Из конца строки можно убрать: `s = s.rstrip('\0')` Лучше узнайте откуда данные (почему NUL в тексте) и исправьте источник.

Comment: Да я уже понял это, разбираемся