# Замена подстроки значениями из списка

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
 "$1.234.567,89 gjhv $1.02 $1.203,20 ghjb $1.205 $63"
```

и есть список:

```
 ['$1,234,567.89', '$1.02', '$1,203.20', '$1,205', '$63']
```

Как заменить каждую сумму в строке соответствующим значением из списка? Порядок значений в списке соответствует порядку в строке. 
Я в регулярных выражениях не сильна. Пробовала с помощью метода `sub` и вызовом функции внутри него, но функция возвращает только первое значение списка (или просто метод sub берёт только первое значение).

```
import re
text = "$1.234.567,89 gjhv $1.02 $1.203,20 ghjb $1.205 $63"
numbers_list = ['$1,234,567.89', '$1.02', '$1,203.20', '$1,205', '$63']
def num(n):
    for n in numbers_list:
        return n

a = re.sub(r'\$[\d,.]*\b', num, text)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У вас все верно сделано, кроме функции num(n). При каждом вызове она читает список numbers_list и возвращает его первый элемент. Чтобы вы не меняли весь код, попробуйте сделать так:

```
def num(n):
    for n in numbers_list:
        numbers_list.remove(n)
        return n
```

Это позволит получать нужный элемент из списка, но он будет "очищаться". Если он нужен в целом виде, можете создать его копию

Comment: это вы `number_list.pop(0)` пытаетесь реализовать? Для замены, для примера в вопросе, pop(0) может даже сработать, но это какой-то окольный путь.

Comment: Я бы вообще такое решение не применял, можно сделать одной строчкой через itertools.chain и map, предварительно разделив сплитом строку text. Цель ответа - показать, где ошибка в коде, чтобы человек понял. Не могу же я ответить - изучи модуль itertools. И данное решение правильное, хоть и некорректное. И автору вопроса помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать итератор из списка и получать следующее значение с помощью `next()`:

```
import re
text = "$1.234.567,89 gjhv $1.02 $1.203,20 ghjb $1.205 $63"
numbers_list = ['$1,234,567.89', '$1.02', '$1,203.20', '$1,205', '$63']
it = iter(numbers_list) # Создаем итератор

def replacer(match):    # Обрабатываем совпадение
    return next(it)     # Возвращаем значение и передвигаем индекс итератора

print(re.sub(r'\$\d[\d,.]*\b', replacer, text))
# => $1,234,567.89 gjhv $1.02 $1,203.20 ghjb $1,205 $63
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/fVkbTT)

А ещё вот одно решение оригинальной проблемы (преобразование чисел из одного формата в другой):

```
import re, locale

text = "$1.234.567,89 gjhv $1.02 $1.203,20 ghjb $1.205 $63"

def repl(m):
    fraction = len(m.group(2)) if m.group(2) else 0
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US')
    return "${}".format(locale.format("%.{}f".format(fraction), float(m.group(1).replace(".","").replace(",", ".")), True))

print(re.sub(r'\$(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,(\d+))?)', repl, text))
# => $1,234,567.89 gjhv $1.02 $1,203.20 ghjb $1,205 $63
```

[Ещё одно демо](http://rextester.com/FRFF60621)

Тут [`\$(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,(\d+))?)`](https://regex101.com/r/63H8wo/1) находит числа после `$` в формате `x.xxx,xxxxxx`, конвертирует число в американский английский формат (`locale.format("%.{}f".format(fraction), float(m.group(1).replace(".","").replace(",", ".")), True)`) с соблюдением количества цифр после запятой (см. 
 `fraction`, определяемой как `len(m.group(2)) if m.group(2) else 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы поработал над листом значений. Создай из него список словарей где ключ будет строка с поменяными точками и запятыми. Потом можно искать ключ в строке и заменять на значение.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите заменить в денежных суммах запятые на точки и наоборот точки на запятые:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\$[\d,.]+', lambda m: m.group().replace(',', '\0').replace('.', ',').replace('\0', '.'), text)
'$1,234,567.89 gjhv $1,02 $1,203.20 ghjb $1,205 $63'
```

Это предполагает, что в тексте нет [`U+0000` символа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685870/23044) (крайне вероятно).

Если просто каждую сумму на последующий элемент списка хотите заменить, то итератор можно использовать:

```
>>> replacements = ['$1,234,567.89', '$1.02', '$1,203.20', '$1,205', '$63']  
>>> re.sub(r'\$[\d,.]+', lambda _, it=iter(replacements): next(it), text)
'$1,234,567.89 gjhv $1.02 $1,203.20 ghjb $1,205 $63'
```

Возможно, при создании текста, следует сразу правильное форматирование использовать:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8')  # the name is platform dependent
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> [locale.currency(amount, grouping=True) for amount in money]
['$1,234,567.89', '$1.02', '$1,203.20', '$1,205.00', '$63.00']
```

Чтобы не менять глобальную locale (полезно в многопоточных приложениях и для переносимости), [можно babel модуль использовать](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html#babel.numbers.format_currency):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> from babel.numbers import format_currency  # $ pip install babel
>>> amount = Decimal('1234567.89')
>>> print(format_currency(amount, 'USD', locale='en_US'))
$1,234,567.89
>>> print(format_currency(amount, 'RUR', locale='ru_RU'))
1 234 567,89 р.
```